# Json not showing in table using date script

Tags: javascript, html, json, cordova

the script below works with json when var is pointed to json data, but i need it to work with a json file, this file is set-up as the following:

```
  0 (top level) > 0 (January) > 1 (1st of each month) Final is the json data:

 var json = [{
    "d_date": "22nd",
    "fajr_begins": "John Doe",
    "fajr_jamah": "10",
    "Sunrise_begins": "1",
    "Zuhur_jamah": "Jane Smith",
    "Zuhur_begins": "15",
    "Jummah_begins": "2",
    "Jummah_jamah": "Chuck Berry",
    "Asr_begins": "12",
    "Asr_jamah": "2"
  }];
```

the json data would be displayed using the time code which would chose from the json file

```js
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var month = currentTime.getMonth()
  var day = currentTime.getDate()
  var dv = ('0' + '/' + month + '/' + day)

  var json = (src= 'json/file.json')

$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<tr> <th colspan='4'>Daily Prayer Times</th> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th rowspan='8' bgcolor='#4da6ff'>" + json[i].d_date + "</th> <th> Prayer </th> <th> Start </th> <th> Jammat </th> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Fajr</th> <td>" + json[i].fajr_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].fajr_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Sunrise</th> <td>" + json[i].Sunrise + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Sunrise + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Zuhur</th> <td>" + json[i].Zuhur_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Zuhur_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Jummah</th> <td>" + json[i].Jummah_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Jummah_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Asr</th> <td>" + json[i].Asr_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Asr_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Magrib</th> <td>" + json[i].Maghrib_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Maghrib_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Isha</th> <td>" + json[i].Isha_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Isha_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    $('#djprayer2').append(tr);
  }
});

/*json content below*/
```

```css
table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="djprayer2"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've lots of refrence errors and extra `[ ]` 
In javascript `[]` is an array and `{}` is an object

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var currentTime = new Date()
  var month = currentTime.getMonth()
  var day = currentTime.getDate()
  var dv = ('0' + '/' + month + '/' + day)

  var json = 
    [
       {
        "asr_jamah": "",
        "asr_mithl": "2:18 PM",
        "d_date": "1st",
        "fajr_begins": "6:09 AM",
        "fajr_jamah": "",
        "isha_begins": "6:10 PM",
        "isha_jamah": "",
        "Jummah_begins": "",
        "jummah_prayer_jamah": "13:30",
        "maghrib_begins": "4:05 PM",
        "maghrib_jamah": "4:10 PM",
        "Sunrise_begins": "8:13 AM",
        "Zuhur_begins": "12:09 PM",
        "zuhr_jamah": "1:30pm"
      }
    ]
  
  var tr;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<tr> <th colspan='4'>Daily Prayer Times</th> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th rowspan='8' bgcolor='#4da6ff'>" + json[i].d_date + "</th> <th> Prayer </th> <th> Start </th> <th> Jammat </th> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Fajr</th> <td>" + json[i].fajr_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].fajr_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Sunrise</th> <td>" + json[i].Sunrise_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Sunrise_begins + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Zuhur</th> <td>" + json[i].Zuhur_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Zuhur_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Jummah</th> <td>" + json[i].Jummah_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Jummah_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Asr</th> <td>" + json[i].Asr_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Asr_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Magrib</th> <td>" + json[i].Magrib_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Magrib_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    tr.append("<tr> <th>Isha</th> <td>" + json[i].Isha_begins + "</td> <td>" + json[i].Isha_jamah + "</td> </tr>");
    $('#djprayer2').append(tr);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="djprayer2"></table>
```

Comment: sorry i think you picked the wrong one (recently edited this) i added a link to my fiddle i should have the extra [] because of the way the file is connected to other things. the table is popluated based on json data which is chosen based on day month

Comment: thank you for spending time to help me but i want the var json to point to a file and table to be populated based on the time code. i rewrote my question as to help.